# Facebook FQL PHP - Get Friend's Friendlist?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql, friend

In FQL/PHP, how to get the `friendlist` of a friend? I can not find in the Facebook Developer API Documentations also.

I used something similar like this:

```
SELECT uid, first_name, last_name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = 'UID_OF_A_FRIEND_HERE')
```

Answer (score 1):

Yep, that syntax is correct, you can check it on the [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?fql=SELECT%20uid,%20first_name,%20last_name%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20IN%20%28SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20=%20%274%27%29), however will only work if A) The friends privacy settings allow it, and B) The friend is a user of your app.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT uid, first_name, last_name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

i just check with Facebook Graph API Explorer. it works